# Basic Auth com Ionic e AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Sou desenvolvedor Android/iOS nativo e agora estou começando a estudar Ionic para desenvolvimento hibrido. Preciso fazer uma conexão com um webservice que usa Basic Auth e não estou encontrando como fazer isso, encontrei alguns exemplos com muito código escrito, por exemplo esse: http://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/ e mesmo assim não usa Basic Auth. Acredito que seja algo simples, mas não estou encontrando.

Como fazer isso ?

Comment: Vai ser difícil achar mesmo. Em desenvolvimento de aplicativos híbridos se usa bastante o [JSON Web Tokens](http://jwt.io/) para fazer auth, estou com um problema meio parecido, usando um webservice restful disponibilizado pelo apex5 workspace.

Comment: @devgaspa encontrei esse exemplo http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx estou tentando implementar, qquer coisa posto aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
$http.get('http://myserver.com/api', { headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic '+ base64.encode( username + ':' + password) } })
```

debugue no Developer-Tools do Chrome, aba Network